# When using Pick_Contact, after i choose a Contact it open ups Android Market

Tags: android

help please

here is my code on onClick

```
    if(v.getId()==R.id.btnContacts)
      {
          Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
          startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);
      }
```

here is my code on onActivityResult

```
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
          Uri contactData = data.getData();
          Cursor c = managedQuery(contactData, null, null, null, null);
       if (c.moveToFirst()) {
       String id =   
         c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

       String hasPhone =
       c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER));

       if (hasPhone.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
      Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query( 
                   ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null, 
                   ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = "+ id, 
                   null, null);
         phones.moveToFirst();
         String cNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex("data1"));
         TextView txtPhoneNo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_PhoneNo);
         txtPhoneNo.setText(cNumber);
         c.close();
```

i dont know what's happening have tried a dozen solutions but its still the same, im running this in my Galaxy Tab

Answer (score 0):

You're assuming that the data returned by the People app in response to `startActivityForResult` is a Uri. Are you sure? I think it returns the `_ID` value of the contact the user selected.

You're retrieving this `_ID` value by doing `getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID)`, but that makes no sense if the user already picked the contact. The semantics of `ACTION_PICK` are that it should return only one row, unless otherwise stated.

Another error: In the query on the Phone URI, you're appending the id value you got for the contact. However, the value `Phone.CONTACT_ID` is the `_ID` value of the *raw* contact for that data row, not the `_ID` value of the contact. The table hierarchy is

```
contact
   |
raw contact(s)
   |
data (phone, email, etc.)
```

A contact can have multiple raw contacts, but a raw contact has only one contact parent. You can't create contacts yourself; they're "aggregated" from raw contacts. Each raw contact represents a person added from a particular account and account type (for example, adding a person to Google Contacts associated with thomas.edison@gmail.com adds a raw contact for a Google Contacts account type for the account named "thomas.edison@gmail.com"). Data rows link to an *individual* raw contact, not to the contact.

You can either dig in AOSP to find out what the Contacts app returns in response to `ACTION_PICK`, or send the Intent and run debug to see what the result data is.

As a note, `managedQuery()` is deprecated. It's better to use the Loader framework.